# How do you move a sprite in pygame?

Tags: python, animation, pygame, sprite

I know that this question has already been answered in other forms, but I can't seem to make it work for my game. I'm trying to make the sprite move and keep him in the place he moved to. This is part of my code:

```
class player(pygame.sprite.Sprite):
    def __init__(self, x, y):
        pygame.sprite.Sprite.__init__(self)

    def draw(self, x, y):

        player = pygame.image.load("stand_down.png").convert_alpha()
        player = pygame.transform.scale(player, (100, 200))
        screen.blit(player, (x, y))
        pygame.display.update()
        for event in pygame.event.get():
            key = pygame.key.get_pressed()
            if event.type == KEYDOWN :
                if key [K_LEFT] :
                    player = pygame.image.load("standleft.png").convert_alpha()
                    player = pygame.transform.scale(player, (100, 200))
                    x -= 50
                    screen.blit(player, (x, y))
                    pygame.display.update()
                    pygame.sprite.Sprite.update(player)
                if key [K_RIGHT]:
                    player = pygame.image.load("standright.png").convert_alpha()
                    player = pygame.transform.scale(player, (100, 200))
                    x += 50
                    screen.blit(player, (x, y))
                    pygame.display.update()
                    pygame.sprite.Sprite.update(player)

    def update(self):
        pygame.sprite.Sprite.update(player)
```

And then this is part of my main function:

```
player.draw(screen, x, y)
player.update(screen)
```

I've tried everything I can think of, but the player just keeps flashing at a different point, then returning to the previous position. If you could help, it would be much appreciated!

Comment: if you use `event.type == KEYDOWN` then use `event.key == K_LEFT`

Comment: don't use `pygame.display.update()` in every place - it can flicker screen -  use it only once in loop.

Comment: don't load image in `draw()` again and again - it slows down program - do it only once in `__init__`

Comment: don't `blit(player)` in three places in `draw()` - it slow down program - do it only once at the end of `draw()`

Comment: use `for event in pygame.event.get():` outside player - you may have events which you will have to send to second player or other object. Inside player use only `if event.type == KEYDOWN :` - it is good idea to create separated method `handle_event(self, event)`

Comment: BTW: read [PEP 8 -- Style Guide for Python Code](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0008/) - it suggest to use `UpperCaseNames` for classes - ie. `class Player()` and `lower_case_names` for other elements ie. instance `player = Player()`

Comment: read doc for [Sprite.update()](http://pygame.org/docs/ref/sprite.html#pygame.sprite.Sprite) - "The default implementation of this method does nothing; it’s just a convenient “hook” that you can override." - it means you don't have to use it in Player

Comment: `event.type == KEYDOWN` and `get_pressed()` works in different way. `event` is created only once when key changes state from `not-pressed` to `pressed`, but it is not created when you keep key pressed. `get_pressed()` returns `True` all the time when you keep key pressed. And this is why you shouldn't mix both when you check keys in draw(). With your code you should check only `if key [K_LEFT] ` , `if key [K_RIGHT]:` without `for event` and without `if event.type == KEYDOWN :`

Comment: [Program Arcade Games With Python And Pygame](http://programarcadegames.com/)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I can't test it but I would do this

```
# --- classes ---

class Player(pygame.sprite.Sprite): # UpperCaseName for class

    def __init__(self, x, y):
        super().__init__()

        temp_image = pygame.image.load("stand_down.png").convert_alpha()
        self.image_down = pygame.transform.scale(temp_image, (100, 200))

        temp_image = pygame.image.load("standleft.png").convert_alpha()
        self.image_left = pygame.transform.scale(temp_image, (100, 200))

        temp_image = pygame.image.load("standright.png").convert_alpha()
        self.image_right = pygame.transform.scale(temp_image, (100, 200))

        self.image = self.image_down

        # keep position and size in pygame.Rect()
        # to use it in collision checking
        self.rect = self.image.get_rect(x=x, y=y)

    def draw(self, screen):
        screen.blit(self.image, self.rect)

    def handle_event(self):#, event)
        self.image = self.image_down

        key = pygame.key.get_pressed()
        if key[K_LEFT]:
            self.rect.x -= 50
            self.image = self.image_left
        if key[K_RIGHT]:
            self.rect.x += 50
            self.image = self.image_right

    def update(self, enemy):
        # check collision with eneny
        if self.rect.colliderect(enemy.rect):
            print("I'm killed by enemy")

# --- main ---

player = Player(400, 400)
enemy = Enemy(100, 100)

while True:

    # - events -

    for event in pygame.event.get():
        #player.handle_event(event)

    player.handle_event()

    # - updates -

    enemy.update()
    player.update(enemy)

    # - draws -

    screen.fill( (0,0,0) )                  
    player.draw(screen)
    enemy.draw(screen)
    pygame.display.update()
```

Comment: Thank you so much, but I keep getting the same error, that "pygame.Surface" object has no attribute to "image_down." How do I fix that?

Comment: It seems you have mistake in different place. Maybe you do `player = player.image` or `player = player.resize()` like in this problem https://stackoverflow.com/q/47732591/1832058

Comment: if you still have problem then create new question (using button `Add Question`) and put code and **full** Traceback. There is many useful informations in full Traceback. ie. it shows which line of code makes problem.

Comment: BTW: you can always use `print(variable)` and `print(type(variable))` to check what you have in variable which makes problem. And then you have find place when variable still gives correct `type(variable)`