# Issue with script using Pygame

Tags: python-2.7, class, pygame

I'm writing a small game in my spare time. This is what I have so far:

```
from pygame import * #import relevant modules
from PIL import Image
import os, sys

init() #initialise

class sprite:

    def __init__(self, object, x = 0, y = 0, w = 0, h = 0):
        self.image = image.load(object).convert()
        self.posx = x
        self.posy = y
        self.position = ((x, y, w, h))

    def resize(self, sh, sw):
        self.image = transform.scale(self.image, (sh, sw))
        return self.image

    def move(self, window, background, right, down):
        self.posx = x + right
        self.posy = y + down
        window.blit(background, self.position, self.position)
        self.position.move(right, down)
        window.blit(self, self.position)
        window.update()




os.chdir('C:\\Users\\alesi\\Documents\\Pygame\\Project\\') #current folder change

win = display.set_mode((736, 552))#load window
Clock = time.Clock() #handy clock

background = image.load('background.jpg').convert()#load images
player = sprite('ball.png', 350, 275, 20, 20)
player = player.resize(20, 20)

win.blit(background, (0, 0))
win.blit(player, (350, 275))
display.update()

while True:
    event.pump()
    keys = key.get_pressed()
    if keys[K_ESCAPE]:
        sys.exit()
    elif keys[K_RIGHT]:
        player.move(win, background, 20, 0)
    elif keys[K_LEFT]:
        player.move(win, background, -20, 0)
    elif keys[K_DOWN]:
        player.move(win, background,0, 20)
    elif keys[K_UP]:
        player.move(win, background, 0, -20)
```

In short, it should create an object on a background and allow you to move the object using the arrow keys. However, I get the error:

```
C:\Users\alesi\Documents\Pygame\Project>python2 game2.py
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "game2.py", line 51, in <module>
    player.move(win, background, -20, 0)
AttributeError: 'pygame.Surface' object has no attribute 'move'
```

I'm struggling to understand why my player instance of the sprite class is not recognising the move method. Also, I'm confused by why during the win.blit() function, I have to give the argument player instead of player.image, the attribute which I've stored the image.

Any advice would be appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

In code

```
def resize(self, sh, sw):
    self.image = transform.scale(self.image, (sh, sw))
    return self.image
```

you returns image which is `Surface` instance - so in line

```
player = player.resize(20, 20)
```

you replace `sprite` instance with `Surface` instance

But you don't have to assign it to `player` again.

Do:

```
def resize(self, sh, sw):
    self.image = transform.scale(self.image, (sh, sw))
    # without return

# without player = 
player.resize(20, 20)
```

After that `player.move(...)`  will work again.
And again you will have to use `player.image` in  `blit()`